# Get legend outside plot on tikz and customise axis labels

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, legend

I've made a schematic plot in tikz with the below code.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{ticks=none}
\begin{axis}[
xlabel=$Treatment$,
ylabel=$Level of donation$]
\addplot[smooth,mark=*,blue] plot coordinates {
    (1,1)
    (2,1)
    (3,1)
};
\addlegendentry{Pure Altruism}

\addplot[smooth,color=red,mark=x]
plot coordinates {
    (1,1)
    (2,2)
    (3,1)
};
\addlegendentry{Warm Glow}

\addplot[smooth,color=green,mark=x]
plot coordinates {
    (1,1)
    (2,3)
    (3,3)
};
\addlegendentry{Mental Accounting}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}#
```

My problem is twofold. First, I want to get the legend outside the plot. Second, I want to add my own, non-numeric labels to the x axis. I want these labels to be treatment names, rather than numbers. How can I make both these adjustments?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](//tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 11):

This answer is very similar to the already provided ones. The main differences are:

- used `legend pos=outer north east`
- used `xtick=data` instead of providing the entries "manually"
- used `typeset ticklabels with strut`, and
- some other minor changes/improvements of the code.

For details please have a look at the comments in the code.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.15
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{
        % use this `compat' level or higher to use the advanced positioning of
        % the axis labels
        compat=1.3,
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        % (normal text should not be set in math mode)
        xlabel=Treatment,
        ylabel=Level of donation,
        % if you use `data' ticks will be set on every x coordinate that is
        % given by the *first* `\addplot' command
        xtick=data,
        xticklabels={
            one month,
            one year,
            one decade%
        },
        ytick=\empty,
        % use the following key so the baseline of all ticklabel entries is the same
        % (compare this image to the one from marmot)
        typeset ticklabels with strut,
        % there is one default value for the `legend pos' that is outside the axis
        legend pos=outer north east,
        % (so the legend looks a bit better)
        legend cell align=left,
        % (moved this common key here)
        smooth,
    ]
        % (renamed `plot coordinates' by `coordinates'
        \addplot [mark=*,blue] coordinates {
            (1,1)
            (2,1)
            (3,1)
        };

        \addplot [color=red,mark=x] coordinates {
            (1,1)
            (2,2)
            (3,1)
        };

        \addplot [color=green,mark=x] coordinates {
            (1,1)
            (2,3)
            (3,3)
        };

        % (replaced `\addlegendentry's with `\legend')
        \legend{
            Pure Altruism,
            Warm Glow,
            Mental Accounting,
        }
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Answer (score 3):

There you go:

[image]

You can configure the `legend style` to place it outside the plot, and manually adjust the `xtick` and the respective `xticklabels`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
% \pgfplotsset{ticks=none}
\begin{axis}[
legend style={at={(1,1)},anchor=north west},
xtick={1,2,3},
xticklabels={One,Two,Three},
xlabel=$Treatment$,
ylabel=$Level of donation$]
\addplot[smooth,mark=*,blue] plot coordinates {
    (1,1)
    (2,1)
    (3,1)
};
\addlegendentry{Pure Altruism}

\addplot[smooth,color=red,mark=x]
plot coordinates {
    (1,1)
    (2,2)
    (3,1)
};
\addlegendentry{Warm Glow}

\addplot[smooth,color=green,mark=x]
plot coordinates {
    (1,1)
    (2,3)
    (3,3)
};
\addlegendentry{Mental Accounting}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This time you were faster.

Comment: @marmot I didn't realize this was a competition ;)

Comment: I did not start making these comments. ;-) (I was just kidding ;-)

Comment: I know nothing about it... (←_←) blame @CarLaTeX... (→_→)

Comment: Naahh, can't blame @CarLaTeX. How can anyone seriously blame a duck? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Very similar to Phelype Oleinik's nice answer, but with a different interpretation of "legend outside".

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[legend to name=named,
xlabel=$Treatment$,
ylabel=$Level of donation$,
xticklabels={one month, one year, one decade},xtick={1,2,3},
ytick={},yticklabels={}]
\addplot[smooth,mark=*,blue] plot coordinates {
    (1,1)
    (2,1)
    (3,1)
};
\addlegendentry{Pure Altruism}

\addplot[smooth,color=red,mark=x]
plot coordinates {
    (1,1)
    (2,2)
    (3,1)
};
\addlegendentry{Warm Glow}

\addplot[smooth,color=green,mark=x]
plot coordinates {
    (1,1)
    (2,3)
    (3,3)
};
\addlegendentry{Mental Accounting}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\ref{named} % see pgfplots manual p. 266
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It is prettier, indeed, but slower :P

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I'm very drowsy during hibernation time, and hence slow. ;-)